# How do I tell my parents that I want to leave Catholicism and become a Protestant?

Tags: relationships, religion

I was raised as a Catholic--which I now believe supports idol worship (e.g. the saints and Mary). I simply want to leave and convert to Protestantism. However, my parents especially hate Protestants. I have a Protestant friend and once I told my parents about her, they told me not to play with her (I didn’t listen to them, of course), I am not sure why, but I am pretty sure that they’re ‘loving’ one another. Now, my mom forces me to go to the Catholic Church with her every Sunday. They are extremely annoying. I really want to leave the Catholic Church, but how should I tell them without getting scolded, failing or becoming deaf?

Comment: As both may be relevant: how old are you, and what country are you in?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "becoming deaf"? Do you mean that your parents will not listen?

Comment: Age, housing/schooling status and culture/location/country would all be very helpful. The answers will be different if you are say, a highschooler than if you are a university/college student. Similarly the answers change if you rely on your parents for financial support or not. (I'm assuming highschool, but we all know how accurate assumptions can be...)

Comment: This sounds very much like a rant disguised as a question. Please make significant edits removing the hostility (all of it) and flag for reopening, if another question in the sidebar doesn't already answer it.

Comment: I am 13 and I am in Hong Kong. I am a college student and I have a little money (about $500 hkd). The meaning of becoming deaf is my parents scold me so loudly that my ears are deaf.

Comment: As an evangelical christian, I was surprised to find that core Catholic doctrine does not call for worship of the saints. Saints are honored and believed to have a special relationship to God, but prayers to the saints are considered little different from asking a friend to pray for you. I would expect your Protestant church to advise you to honor your parents, then make your choice when you are an adult and leave home. The religious climate in China complicates matters - some "unofficial" churches can be a magnet for trouble with Beijing, which is a reason for your parents to be concerned.

Comment: You should try ask this question on: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ that's is dedicated to how to communicate things inter-personally. Good luck to you!

Comment: If you want more of a discussion, then I'd actually suggest finding a forum (the "old school" vBulletin style things) or a reddit about this topic (the r/Christianity sub seems to be well moderated). SE (even the interpersonal one) is really more for Q&A as opposed to discussion, and this question/topic seems like you could benefit more from a back-and-forth discussion.